# constants in asymptotic notations

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I've question from **CLRS** that's about constants and functions in asymptotic notations.

> *$\Theta (g(n)) = \{f(n) :there\;exist\; positive\;constants\;c_1, c_2, n_0\;such\;that$*
> $0 \leqslant c_1g(n)\leqslant f(n) \leqslant c_2g(n)\; \forall \;n\geqslant n_0 \}.$

Why do we require positive constants here, what is the main reason for this? Secondly, why $g(n)$ and $f(n)$ need to be asymptotically nonnegative functions. What happens when $g(n)$ and $f(n)$  is asymptotically negative and the above constants negative also? Why do we restrict the general case to above?

Comment: In general case there are absolute values of functions in definitions, so positive constants are natural.

Comment: They restrict $f$ and $g$ to positive functions since they mainly care about things like memory and running time, which are nonnegative. I guess it makes the definition slightly simpler since you don't need absolute values.